# What causes this strange behavior of the enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am using the enumerate environment and something strange happened.  Here's the line of LaTeX code that causes the strange behavior:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\bf Some List  \#1:\ }]
```

With this, the list produced has headings of the following form:

**Some L1st #1:** Blah Blah Blah

**Some L2st #2:** Blah Blah Blah

The way I eventually corrected this was to modify that specific line to read as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\bf {Some List}  \#1:\ }]
```

Thus my question about this is somewhat academic, because I have a fix.  I just have no idea why it happens, and I have no idea why this fix works.  Another reason to ask this question is that while for me the answer is somewhat academic, the discussion of this issue may help someone else.  Finally, a reason for asking this is that while this strange behavior was perplexing, both my discovery of it and of my solution just made me laugh, and I think I have no right to deprive others of that moment of mirth.  :)

Comment: really 1 2..?? I would have expected roman numerals i ii iii iv ... In either case it isn't the standard `enumerate `behaviour. I would guess you are using the `enumerate` package but you have not said. It would be a lot clearer if you provided a small complete document that showed the problem, so people could debug.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem adding the enumerate package.  Strange the `i` from ‘List’ is output as an arabic value of the counter…

Comment: @Bernard it's a documented feature:-) The argument has both `i` and `1` so the last one (1 here) wins.

Comment: I knew about the feature, but I expected  both a roman number, then an arabic.

Comment: @Bernard each special character is replaced by `\thexxxx` and `\thexxxx` defined to be the appropriate command so first `i` defines it to be `\roman` then `1` defines it to be `arabic` but both are replaced by `\thexxxx`

Answer (score 2):

The output you get is essentially random.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

Wrong:
\begin{enumerate}[{\bf Some List  \#1:\ }]
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}

Right:
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries Some {List} \#1:\ ]
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the `enumitem` package is easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Some List \#\arabic*:]
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\bf` has been obsolete for more than twenty years.

Comment: If \bf is obsolete, when I use it, why don't I get a warning?  I have only used LaTeX since the late 1990s, when all the examples I learned from used \bf for boldface.  Moreover, still all of my collaborators seem to never bat an eye when I use \bf, and when I begin to collaborate with them, usually they use \bf for boldface as well without me "prompting" them in any way.  No one until now told me that \bf is obsolete.

Comment: @MattInsall `\bf` and the other two-letter font changing commands have been deprecated since 1994. Inertia and unwillingness of reading manuals.

Comment: ...this answers part of my query, but why no warnings?

Comment: @MattInsall The commands are defined in the standard classes for back compatibility. You don't want that your pre-1994 documents start spitting out warnings or errors, do you? Add to it that memory in 1994 was very scarce and there were much more important things than issuing those warnings.

Comment: This is not 1994, so the warnings could have been added by now surely.  Also, I now use interfaces that give me command suggestions, like overleaf, etc.  These do not suggest commands to me other than \bf when I type \bf, but for other commands, I do get very useful suggestions.  Thus the question whether someone uses \bf or not should not automatically kick up a comment that it has been obsolete for over 20 years, especially since so many people use it and it still works.  Mainly, because it still works, that comment is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

note that `\bf` should not be used in latex.

You are presumably using the `enumerate` package although you have not said.

In the optional argument to `enumerate` as defined by that package `i` triggers the use of roman numerals so

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{List}]
\item zzzz
\item zzzz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

produces List, Liist

But you also have `1` in the option so this redefines the counter to use 1,2

```
\begin{enumerate}[{List 1}]
```

produces L1st 1, L2st 2.

Normally `{}` hides the special tokens, but low level tex parse rules mean that a `{}` group that is the entire optional argument is dropped.

Comment: Why should \bf not be used in LaTeX?  That is how I have made boldface characters since time immemorial...

Comment: @MattInsall `\bf`  is defined in plain tex and was defined in latex2.09 but since latex2e came out in 1993 it has not been defined in the latex format.. Some classes, such as article, define it as a legacy compatibility command to help convert latex2.09 documents to the "new" latex2e format. In other classes eg the Koma classes, it is undefined.

Comment: Like I asked egreg, why does not LaTeX warn me and point me to the right command?  I don't recall ever seeing any such warnings.

Comment: @MattInsall if you use an undefined command such as `\khlglj`  you just get an undefined command error, latex can't make it give a command-specific message without actually defining it.

Comment: We are not talking about an undefined command.  We are talking about something that works and you say it is deprecated, obsolete, etc.

Comment: No I did not say it is deprecated I said it is undefined. The latex format does not define it so if you write a document class and use `\bf` in your document, then it is simply an undefined command, unlike `\textbf{zzz}` which is bold.  If you use `article` class then _that class_ defines `\bf`, so with `article` class it works. The standard latex manual, Lamport's LaTeX Book, never mentions `\bf` at all.

Comment: @MattInsall try `\documentclass{minimal} \begin{document}\textbf{zz} zz {\bf zz}\end{document}`

Comment: I just got this message from the StackExchange system:  "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?".  I clicked on the link to move this to chat and was told automatically that I cannot move this to chat.  Catch22, might you not say?  

@DavidCarlisle, in your first comment you wrote "note that \bf should not be used in latex.", so perhaps I should have pointed out that I am using the "article" class or the "amsart" class almost exclusively, but presumably you would say that I should not use those document classes. lol

Comment: Why should I try \documentclass{minimal} \begin{document}\textbf{zz} zz {\bf zz}\end{document}?  My main use of LaTeX is to write articles for mathematics journals that often use amsart documentclass or article documentclass, or they will provide me an appropriate template.

Comment: @MattInsall `article` and `amsart` happen to define `\bf` for compatibility with similar pre-1994 latex2.09 styles.  So if you use those classes then `\bf` is defined. (but naturally it is bad style to be using a legacy compatibility command 30 years after it was introduced). I just suggested minimal class so you could see what I am saying, the latex format does not define `\bf`. It is not "defined but deprecated", it is not defined, and has not been defined since latex2e was introduced.

Comment: obviously there is nothing wrong with using article or amsart.